# how to compaire Auth::user()->id and user_id and run if else command in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need check My Laravel app with current  logging user id(Auth) and user_id in task table and run if else command. I need show task_name in task table with different user_id. among them if user_id is equal to current I need show following items on My blade file.

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>

    </span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

and if task user_id is not equels to Auth id should display following items

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
    <li>
  <div>
  <div class="pull-right icons-align">
            <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a>
</span></h4>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
<hr>
@endforeach
```

how can do this?

**My task table as this**

```
id task_name user_id
 1    dfr       1
 2    bgh       2
 3    hyg       1
 4    hyu       4
```

Comment: no any ideas about this matter?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: You need to compare auth user with your user variable like auth()->user()->id with $task->user_id.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to filter the tasks in your controller, before passing them to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `auth()` helper. These helpers are available on both blade files and Controllers.

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
   @if(auth()->user()->id == $task->user_id)
     // do something
   @else
     // do something
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Then that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `auth` user with your `task user` variable in if condition and then display the data like below:

```
@if(auth()->user()->id == $task->user_id)
   @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
   <ul>
     <li>
      <div>
       <div class="pull-right icons-align">
        <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
       </a>
        </div>
       <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}
       </a>
     </span></h4>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
<hr>
@endforeach   
@else
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
  <ul>
   <li>
   <div>
      <div class="pull-right icons-align">
        <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
       </a>
        <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
     </i></a>
    </div>
       <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}
    </a>
    </span></h4>
    </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <hr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

You can also @if condition within @foreach to just use it once if both @foreach are same and can update your code like below:

```
 @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
 @if(auth()->user()->id == $task->user_id)
   <ul>
     <li>
      <div>
       <div class="pull-right icons-align">
        <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
       </a>
        </div>
       <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}
       </a>
     </span></h4>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
<hr>
@else
  <ul>
   <li>
   <div>
      <div class="pull-right icons-align">
        <a href="{{url('projects/'.$project->id.'/task/'.$task->id.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
       </a>
        <a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/edit" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
     </i></a>
    </div>
       <h4><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> <span><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}
    </a>
    </span></h4>
    </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <hr>
@endif
@endforeach
```